# Compare current month to previous month PBI

Tags: date, powerbi, compare, powerbi-desktop

I have a line graph with ExamCount and FailureRate as the values, with ExamDate on the X axis.

How would I calculate the the current months FailureRate compared to last month? I have two slicers affecting the graph: SchoolName and ExamDate

Answer (score 0):

try with:

```
PrevFailureRate = calculate( sum(Table[Failure]), FLITER(ALL(Table[ExamDate]), Table[ExamDate] = SELECTEDVALUE(Table[ExamDate]) - 1 ))
```

Comment: Thanks, I will bear this in mind, but I managed to do it with the code below.

Previous Month = CALCULATE([ExamFailure],DATEADD('TableName '[ExamDate],-1,MONTH))

Comment: be awared of using DATEADD! read note https://dax.guide/dateadd/
you may get unexpected data. it will be safer to use 
DATA( YEAR(SELECTEDVALUE(Table[ExamDate])), MONTH(SELECTEDVALUE(Table[ExamDate])) - 1, DAY(SELECTEDVALUE(Table[ExamDate]))